# Matrix for a linear transformation on finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix of a linear transformation on a finite-dimensional vector space is defined in SEC. 37. Matrices of the 2nd ed. of "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces" by Paul R. Halmos as follows:

> Let $\mathcal V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, let $\mathbb X = \{x_1, \cdots, x_n\}$ be any basis in $\mathcal V$, and let $A$ be a linear transformation (operator) on $\mathcal V$. Since every vector (in $\mathcal V$) is a linear combination of the $x_i$, we have in particular
> $$\tag{1}Ax_j = \sum_i \alpha_{ij}x_i$$
> for $j = 1, \cdots, n$. The set $(\alpha_{ij})$ of $n^2$ scalars, indexed with the double subscript $i, j$, is the matrix of $A$ in the coordinate system $\mathbb X$.

It is clear from (1) that the $i$th row of the matrix concerns the $i$th "input" ($x_i$), and that the $j$th column of the matrix concerns the $j$th "output" ($Ax_j$). However, I am also able to interpret what a matrix is from Lecture 2 of Autumn Quarter 2007–08 of Stanford University's "EE263 - Linear Dynamical Systems" by Stephen Boyd as follows:

> If $y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\ \vdots \\ y_m\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^m$, if $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^n$, and if $y = Ax$ where $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn}\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, then:
> $$ \tag{2} y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j$$

Expression (2) implies that the $i$th row of the matrix concerns the $i$th "output" ($y_i$), and that the $j$th column of the matrix concerns the $j$th "input" ($x_j$).

Seemingly the matrix definition of (1) is different from that of (2), and that's puzzling. Would appreciate a pointer if I have misunderstood something. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they are different. Indeed, the second is the transpose of the first one.

Comment: There is no difference, but you need to understand what each equation is doing, The equation in Halmos is expressing the vector $Ax_i$ in terms of the vectors $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$. The matrix of the linear transformation is written as $(a_{i,j})$, with $i$ representing rows and $j$ as columns. In your other source, the $x_i$s are not vectors, but coordinates of a single vector. So, if you want to compare to the equations in Halmos, you need to take all the equations in the second reference staked as a column vector and put all $x_j=0$ except for $x_i=1$.

Comment: Also, keep reading further down in Halmos.